# How can I use JavaScript to detect if I am on a cached page

Tags: javascript

I want to display from cache for a long time and I want a slightly different behavior on page render vs loading the page from cache.  Is there an easy way I can determine this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way you could do it is to include the time the page was generated in the page and then use some javascript to compare the local time to the time the page was generated.  If the time is different by a threshold then the page has come from a cache.  The problem with that is if the client machine has its time set incorrectly, although you could get around this by making the client include its current system time in the request to generate the page and then send that value back to the client.

Comment: damn, you beat me to it, thumbs up!

Comment: I was actually thinking of this solution.  I was hoping something easier in the document but maybe it does not exist :)

Comment: This is not a good answer if you're looking for it to work with any consistency.  Between slow load times, server local time vs client local time, or clients with incorrect system dates, you have no way of guaranteeing the veracity of that test.

Answer (score 20):

I started with the answer "Daniel" gave above but I fear that over a slow connection I could run into some latency issues.

Here is the solution that ultimately worked for me.  On the server side I add a cookie refCount and set it's value to 0. On document load in javascript I first check refCount and then increment it.  When checking if refCount is greater than 1 I know the page is cached.  So for this works like a charm.

Thanks guys for leading me to this solution.

Comment: I've used the same approach myself. I wrote up a detailed description on my blog:

http://monket.net/blog/2010/02/detecting-when-a-page-is-loaded-from-the-browser-cache/

Comment: Saved my day! I didn't get why increment the cookie, though. Just set it to “firstLoad=yes” and changed to “firstLoad=no” in `onLoad`. Essentially, the cookie is just a boolean flag that is kept permanently until the page is actually reloaded.

Answer (score 12):

With the new Resource Timing Level 2 spec you can use the transfer size property to check if the page is loaded from cache:

```
var isCached = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].transferSize === 0;
```

- Spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing-2/#dom-performanceresourcetiming-transfersize
- Browser support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming#Browser_compatibility

  - note that at the time of writing, it shows Safari does not support while in actuality the latest version does.

Comment: In my case for firefox 74 win10 the condition shoud be `pnt.transferSize === 0 && pnt.type === 'back_forward'`, otherwise eternal reload.

Answer (score 4):

While this question is already 4 years old. I thought I would add my 2 cents using jQuery and the [History](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('body').append('<div class="is_cached"></div>');
});

History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){
   if($('.is_cached').length >= 1)
   {
      alert('this page is cached');
   }
});
```

When the document is first loaded. A new div.is_cached is appended. There isn't a compatible way to execute javascript when loading a cached page, but you can monitor for history changes. When history changes and the div.is_cached exists, then the user is viewing a cached paged.

Comment: which javascript files should I use to test this? I downloaded History  plugin but it has alot JS files...which one is working with this?

Comment: I used this one with jQuery without any trouble. https://github.com/balupton/history.js/blob/master/scripts/bundled/html4%2Bhtml5/jquery.history.js

Comment: Note: the IF statement should be >= 1

Comment: I tried but nothing happens, I linked history js and latest jqeury js... Please check - http://slgag.com/cd.html

Comment: You are missing the script type for your <script> tag.

Comment: Okay, I changed it but still not working for me...? what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? This checks if the paging being displayed comes from the browser's cache. You need to have a link on the page to take the user forward, and then you can hit the back button to see the alert be displayed.

Comment: "There isn't a compatible way to execute javascript when loading a cached page" wait... my scripts are executing normally even when the page is loaded from cache

Answer (score 2):

Using XmlHttpRequest you can pull up the current page and then examine the http headers of the response.

Best case is to just do a HEAD request and then examine the headers.

For some examples of doing this have a look at http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html

Comment: I was about to suggest the same thing, but the question indicates that he wants to see whether the currently loaded page is cached, if you fire an XHR off, then that would be indicative of the next request, not the current one.

Comment: Thanks, I cannot use this but, the link you sent me helps me with another issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try `performance.getEntriesByType('resource')` API, it will return each stage time and its `name`, `type` of all network resource like this:

[image]

Above screenshot shows we got the file named `https://www.google.com/xjs/_/js/k=xjs...` download total `duration` is 925 (ms), its type is `script`.

So we can detect if some files hit cache based on its `duration`, and filter `type` or `name` we want to focus:

```js
const includeFileTypes = [
  'script',
  // 'css',
  // 'img',
]
const includeFileNames = [
  'yourTargteFileName.js',
]

function getFileNameFromURL(url) {
  return url?.match(/[^\\/]+(?!.*\/)/)?.[0]
}

const getResourceTiming = () => {
  const resources = performance
    .getEntriesByType('resource')
    .filter(({ initiatorType }) => {
      return includeFileTypes.includes(initiatorType)
    })
    // .filter(({ name }) => {
    //   return includeFileNames.includes(getFileNameFromURL(name))
    // });
  return resources.map(
    ({
      name,
      // redirectEnd,
      // redirectStart,
      // domainLookupEnd,
      // domainLookupStart,
      // connectEnd,
      // connectStart,
      // secureConnectionStart,
      responseEnd,
      responseStart,
      // fetchStart,
      // requestStart,
      startTime,
      duration,
    }) => ({
      name: getFileNameFromURL(name),
      startTime: parseInt(startTime),
      endTime: parseInt(responseEnd - responseStart),
      duration: parseInt(duration),
    }),
  );
};

function getHitCacheFiles(allTargetResources) {
  return allTargetResources?.filter(({name, duration}) => {
    if (duration < 20) {
      console.log(`Hit Cache: ${name}`)
      return true
    } else {
      console.log(`Not Hit Cache: ${name}`)
      return false
    }
  })
}


const allTargetResources = getResourceTiming()

console.table(getHitCacheFiles(allTargetResources))
```

### DEMO

It will print:

[image]

It is also align to DevTool Network panel:

[image]

> `getEntriesByType('resource')` usage is simpler than `transferSize`, it don't need extra HTTP header `Timing-Allow-Origin: https://yoursite.com`
>
> References: [transferSize#cross-origin_content_size_information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming/transferSize#cross-origin_content_size_information)

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, some browsers may have some custom command for it.

There is a workaround that would do what you want.  Use a cookie to store `timestamp` of the first visit and then use the META HTTP-EQUIV to set the length of time the file is cached (`cacheLength`).  If the current time is within the time period from `timestamp` to `timestamp+cacheLength` then treat as if they loaded from cache.  Once the cache has expired reset the cookie time.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add unique data to the page on the server at creation. For example a random number, or the creation time:

```
       window.rand = {{ rand() }}
```

2. Use local storage to save the url with the number and compare it later if needed:

```
       reloadIfCached() {
            var cached = localStorage.getItem(window.location.href) == window.rand;
            if (cached) {
                window.location.reload();
            }
            localStorage.setItem(window.location.href, window.rand);
       }
```