# Check browser's cache for a js file

Tags: javascript, http, web-applications, browser, caching

How can  I check for a javascript file in user's cache. If he refreshed the page or visits the site after sometime. I need not download that js file again. Does the js files get cleaned up after a site is closed.

Comment: @MarkAmery can you please link that 'timing attack' check explanation?

Comment: @setec Here's an academic paper on it from 15 years ago: http://sip.cs.princeton.edu/pub/webtiming.pdf. It hasn't been fixed since then, despite being a privacy hole. The tl;dr version is: make an `<img>` tag with `onload` and `onerror` attributes pointing to the URL you're interested in, and use JavaScript to time how long it takes for one of the handlers to get called. If it's under a couple of milliseconds, the user had the target URL cached.

Comment: You can use [transferSize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51817474/975097) to detect cached pages; can cached JavaScript files be detected in the same way?

Answer (score 11):

Whether a javascript file is cached depends on how your web server is setup, how the users browser is setup and also how any HTTP proxy servers between your server and the user are setup. The only bit you can control is how your server is setup.

If you want the best chance of your javascript being cached then you server needs to be sending the right HTTP headers with the javascript file. Exactly how you do that depends on what web server you are using.

Here are a couple of links that might help:

Apache - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html

IIS - http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0fc16fe7-be45-4033-a5aa-d7fda3c993ff.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 6):

To check if a Javascript file is cached works only **if the Javascript file is from the same domain** afaik.

You could then check it like this:

```
try {
    await fetch("https://YOUR-DOMAIN.org/static/build/js/YOUR-FILE.js",
             {method:'Head',cache:'only-if-cached',mode:'same-origin'});
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

You will get a `200` back **if it is cached**, otherwise an error is thrown.

Answer (score 4):

The browser will automatically look after what it has in it's own cache. There are various mechanisms you can use for controlling it however.

Look into the various HTTP caching headers, such as:

- Last-Modified
- Expires
- ETag

The Expires header is the most critical of these when it comes to client-side caching. If you set a far future Expires header (eg, 10 years) the browser will not (in theory) not look to the server again for that file. Of course then you need a method of changing the file name when the contents of the the file change. Most people manage this by adding a build number to the file path.

Answer (score 2):

The browser will take care of caching for you.

When the cache is emptied depends partly on the browser settings and partly on the headers you send.  If you set an `Expires` header, then the browser shouldn't re-request the file until it has expired.  Reading about [HTTP Headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) might help you.