# Check if preload script has already run (elements are in cache)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching, if-statement

I have this jQuery AJAX function that load with the call to .JS on every page in the html

I would like to put an if statement that checks if the files that I want to preload are already in cache. This to avoid that the script will run all its content on every page.
Once everything is in cache we don't need that. And is time consuming to run it!

Note: I want it on every page because I want that preload where ever the client land to the web site. (not only main page)

Here is the preload.js:

```
(function() {
```

here to insert the if statement, should be something like:

```
if(xhr[src="myslide.swf"].status = 200);
alert('cached');
```

or (concept) if myslide.swf is in cache then do nothing; else...

```
}else{
setTimeout(function(){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'myslide.js');
xhr.send('');   
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'myslide.swf');
xhr.send('');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'images.xml');
xhr.send('');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'param.xml');
xhr.send('');
$.ajax({ 
type: "POST", 
url: "/javascript/getnames.php", 
data: "$list",
cache: true,
dataType:"json",
success: function(result) {
    Object.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
      }
     return size;
    };
    // Get the size of an object
    var size = Object.size(result);
    var i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++) new Image().src = "/site/" + result[i];
                /*alert(result[X]);*/
            }
     });  //closes the ajax call
var splashArray = new Array();
// Load the Splash XML file and assign each image within to an array
$.get('/javascript/preloadGallery.xml', function(xml) {
    $('image', xml).each(function (i) {
            splashArray.push($(this).attr("src"));
    });
    work_with_splash();
});
function work_with_splash () {
    Object.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
      }
     return size;
    };
    // Get the size of an object
    var size = Object.size(splashArray);
    var i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++) new Image().src = splashArray[i];
                /*alert(result[X]);*/   
} //closes the spalsh Call
}, 500);
};

})();
```

All the script works perfectly, the only thing I miss is the if statement.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: in the if statement you are assigning instead of checking.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535940/check-browsers-cache-for-a-js-file?answertab=votes#tab-top) if can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446740/post-loading-check-if-an-image-is-in-the-browser-cache) as a starting point, I came up with:

```
var storage = window.localStorage;
if (!storage.cachedElements) {
    storage.cachedElements = "";
}

function logCache(source) {
    if (storage.cachedElements.indexOf(source, 0) < 0) {
        if (storage.cachedElements != "") 
            storage.cachedElements += ";";
        storage.cachedElements += source;
    }
}

function cached(source) {
    return (storage.cachedElements.indexOf(source, 0) >= 0);
}

if (cached("swf")){
}else{
...
xhr.open('GET', 'myslide.js');
xhr.send('');
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: "/myslide.swf",
    success: function(result) {
        logCache("swf");
    }
}
...
```

Let me know how this works out.

EDIT: Here is the only other thing I can think of. You can check how long the ajax request for the swf takes, like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: "/myslide.swf",
    beforeSend: function(){ 
        window.timer = new Date().getTime(); 
    },
    success: function(result) {
        window.timer = (new Date().getTime()) - window.timer;
        if (window.timer > 200) {
            functioncall();
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on the size of your images, it should take considerably less time for the image to load from a cache (a 16.6 kb image for example just went from taking 1.2s to 250ms on my test) If you can fine tune it for this swf, the timer value calculated in the success handler should tell you if it is being loaded from the cache. You can then wrap the rest of the conditional stuff in a function, and call it based on whether timer is above a certain value.

Comment: I've tried that... seems not working. Instead of "swf" in the cached call I've tried the name of file and the full path. None is working.

Comment: are there any exceptions thrown? what happens?

Comment: it just run the script as if element is not in cache... I have pasted what you told me simply changing "swf" with the full path "http://..." of the file. Is that wrong?

Comment: no, it shouldn't matter; localStorage is supposed to hold a semicolon separated string of some sort of tokens that represent a certain resource is loaded. What we use as the token is irrelevant. Try an alert(localStorage) at the beginning of the else and tell me what it gets.

Comment: Now it works! It was just missing a { after the $.ajax( ... Really thanks a lot!

Comment: Well spotted. I am not sure why they rejected your edit request.

Comment: OPS!! I see now that is NOT really working as it consider always as if  elements are cached... also when they are not. Sorry to tell, but still need to be fixed! I'll have a look why, if you have any suggestion is very welcomed!

Comment: if you clear the cache, the localStorage variable should be cleared, no?

Comment: I have tested the script in many different condition. and exactly! if a clear the cache, the variable is not cleaning! Even if I exit the browser or what ever... and if i change the string for cached and check with alert, it returns both strings as an array, which means it does not clean...

Comment: Asad thanks for your advices. At the end, I've chosen for the first option. Why should one clear the cache and reload the site without switching off his computer? Well... in any case it's not really what I was looking for, but it kind of do the job! thanks.