# determine if I'm viewing a cached page

Tags: javascript

I just added a math.random() object to my document.location statement to generate a unique url and prevent the page from being cached.

```
document.location="http://www.my/project/site/" +Math.random()+"";
```

The code produces the desired unique url, but I don't know how to test to verify that the page is not being cached. Is there a javascript method that can detect whether or not a page is a cached page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use JavaScript to detect if I am on a cached page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/260043/851811)

Comment: Other than pages retrieved via ajax, I don't think there's anything in JS that lets you get the http status code for the current page. Would be handy...

Comment: if duplicate, apologies. I looked but didn't see the other page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there's no way in javascript that I know of, but firebug and developer tools in chrome will tell you whether each resource has been cached or not

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug or Developer Tools (w/e your particular browser calls them).

Most of them have a "Network" tab that shows you information about all of the files being used on the page, including, whether or not they are loaded from cache.