# How to check if a particular resource (e.g. image) is cached by the browser?

Tags: javascript

I have a resource that is served with `Cache-Control: public, immutable`, i.e. I expect the resource to exist in the browser's cache for non-first time visitors.

(Browser support for "immutable" configuration is off-topic.)

How to check if a particular resource (e.g. image) is cached by the browser without triggering browser to load the resource?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - Why should that be if your concern?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a JavaScript API for checking if a resource is cached.

Comment: You need to know it from within Javascript? otherwise - Developer Tools will do the job.

Comment: @jswaldon `ServiceWorker`, `Cache`?

Comment: "You need to know it from within Javascript?" From JavaScript. I am aware that dev tools provide this information. It even says whether cache is from memory or disk.

Comment: What do you mean by "without triggering browser to load the resource?"?

Comment: Is it possible to detect cached images using [transferSize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51817474/975097)?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if there is a way to do this from within code. But if you just want to check if a resource is loaded from cache you can check developer tools like @Yani suggested in comments.

1. On your webpage open developer tools. (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I (or Cmd+Opt+I if you are on a Mac).
2. Click on the "network" tab.
3. Make sure the checkbox "disable cache" is not checked.
4. Reload the page (F5 or ctrl+r)
5. In the table in the column "size" it has a size or the text "from disk cache"

[image]

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:javascript].