# How to check if a resource is cached by the browser from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, caching, fetch, abort

Is there a way to check if a resource is cached by the browser without downloading the resource? Most of the questions and answers are old and I believe things have changed now and there are better ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leverage the `fetch` API and it's correspondent `AbortController` to achieve this functionality with a margin of error (expected false negatives).

It goes like this, `fetch` the required resource with a signal attached. Abort in a small amount of time eg. 4ms. If the fetch is returned in the short amount of time it's absolutely cached. If the fetch was aborted, it's probably not cached. Here's some code:

```js
      async checkImageCached(url, waitTimeMs = 4) {
        const ac = new AbortController()
        const cachePromise = fetch(url, {signal: ac.signal})
          .then(() => true)
          .catch(() => false)
        setTimeout(() => ac.abort(), waitTimeMs)
        return cachePromise
      }
```

Comment: **without downloading the resource**

Comment: @JaromandaX it's being aborted quickly, thus it's not being downloaded.

Comment: do you think setTimeout ever triggers in 4ms? I thought 20ms was the minimum usable time (that was years ago though)

Comment: all good :p I learned about AbortController from this answer, so +1 :p and yes, I did try it out after you suggested it, and taking into consideration lag from using console.log, 4ms timeout triggers in 4 or 5ms !

Comment: Isn't it also possible to do this using [Resource Timing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51817474/975097)?

Answer (score 3):

Currently only works on Firefox, unfortunately, but another option is to use [only-if-cached](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache), though it only works for requests on the same origin (because it requires `mode: 'same-origin'` as well):

```
fetch(urlOnSameOrigin, { mode: 'same-origin', cache: 'only-if-cached'})
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log('Cached');
    } else if (response.status === 504) {
      console.log('Not cached');
    }
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('Network error');
  });
```

> only-if-cached — The browser looks for a matching request in its HTTP cache.
>
> - If there is a match, fresh or stale, it will be returned from the cache.
> - If there is no match, the browser will respond with a 504 Gateway timeout status.

Comment: is 'same-origin' required?

Comment: @Seaskyways It looks that way, yes, which is unfortunate, since *some* cross-site resources don't have CORS restrictions which could still be accessed via JS

Comment: I think you can also do this using the [ETag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) header, so that the cache is updated only if the file's contents have changed.