# Chrome extension - check if fetch is loaded from disk cache?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here's part of my code for a Chrome extension:

```
fetch(finalURL).then((response) => {
    if(response.status === 200){
        processDomain(domain);
    }
}).catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

It's processing some information if the response code from my server is `200`.

However, the browser is caching the result and loading 200 from disk cache.  I'm okay with and want it to be that way.  But if it's loaded from disk cache, I don't want to process the domain.

Here's basically what I'm wanting:

```
if(response.status === 200 && NOT LOADED FROM CACHE){
```

I can see in dev tools that it's loaded from cache but can't figure out what to change that line to so I can detect it in the script...

What would I need to change that line to?

Comment: You'll probably have to analyze the response headers or check the time spent. BTW if you only check the status then add `{method: 'HEAD'}` to fetch.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll check to see if I can find any differences in the response or request headers to determine if the cache is being used.

Comment: Well the response headers are identical.  However, it doesn't look like the request headers are the same.  From devtools and docs, it sounds like request headers aren't sent when requesting a URL from cache.  Would there be a way to check what request headers were sent?  And if something like "accept-encoding" doesn't exist, then it must have requested from cache?

Comment: Also, when I download the HAR file for the cached request, I can see this line:  `"_fromCache": "disk"` which doesn't appear in the HAR file for the request to the server.  But I can't find a way to access that response in my extension...

Comment: Another solution appears to be checking `transferSize` and if it's zero then it's loaded from cache - still trying to figure out how to do that though.

Comment: Oh, just found: `fetch(url, {cache: "only-if-cached"})`

Comment: Oh man, I looked forever for something like that!  You should add that as an answer and I'll select it :)

Comment: Looks like someone already answered [How to check if a resource is cached by the browser from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59787487)